# Sitefinity: Dynamic Content query optimization with field values

Tags: c#, sitefinity

I will attempt to be as specific as possible. So we are using **Sitefinity 8.1.5800**, I have a couple dynamic content modules named ReleaseNotes and ReleaseNoteItems. ReleaseNotes has some fields but no reference to ReleaseNoteItems.

Release Note Items has fields and a related data field to ReleaseNotes.

So I can query all ReleaseNoteItems as dynamic content pretty quickly less than a second.

I then use these objects provided by sitefinity and map them to a C# object so I can use strong type. This mapping process is taking almost a minute and using over 600 queries for only 322 items (N+1).

**In Short:** I need to get all sitefinity objects and Map them to a usable c# object quicker than I currently am.

The method for fetching the dynamic content items (takes milliseconds):

---

```
private IList<DynamicContent> GetAllLiveReleaseNoteItemsByReleaseNoteParentId(Guid releaseNoteParentId)
       {
           DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager(String.Empty);
           Type releasenoteitemType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.ReleaseNoteItems.Releasenoteitem");
           string releaseNoteParentTypeString = "Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.ReleaseNotes.Releasenote";
           var provider = dynamicModuleManager.Provider as OpenAccessDynamicModuleProvider;
           int? totalCount = 0;

           var cultureName = "en";
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);


           Type releasenoteType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.ReleaseNotes.Releasenote");

           // This is how we get the releasenote items through filtering

           DynamicContent myCurrentItem = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItem(releasenoteType, releaseNoteParentId);

           var myMasterParent =
               dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.GetMaster(myCurrentItem) as DynamicContent;

           var relatingItems = provider.GetRelatedItems(
                releaseNoteParentTypeString,
                "OpenAccessProvider",
                myMasterParent.Id,
                string.Empty,
                releasenoteitemType,
                ContentLifecycleStatus.Live,
                string.Empty,
                string.Empty,
                null,
                null,
                ref totalCount,
                RelationDirection.Parent).OfType<DynamicContent>();
           IList<DynamicContent> allReleaseNoteItems = relatingItems.ToList();

           return allReleaseNoteItems;
       }
```

---

This is the method that takes almost a minute that is mapping sitefinity object to C# object:

```
public IList<ReleaseNoteItemModel> GetReleaseNoteItemsByReleaseNoteParent(ReleaseNoteModel releaseNoteItemParent)
       {

          return  GetAllLiveReleaseNoteItemsByReleaseNoteParentId(releaseNoteItemParent.Id).Select(rn => new ReleaseNoteItemModel
           {

               Id = rn.Id,
               Added = rn.GetValue("Added") is bool ? (bool)rn.GetValue("Added") : false,
               BugId = rn.GetValue<string>("bug_id"),
               BugStatus = rn.GetValue<Lstring>("bugStatus"),
               Category = rn.GetValue<Lstring>("category"),
               Component = rn.GetValue<Lstring>("component"),
               @Content = rn.GetValue<Lstring>("content"),
               Criticality = rn.GetValue<Lstring>("criticality"),
               Customer = rn.GetValue<string>("customer"),
               Date = rn.GetValue<DateTime?>("date"),
               Grouped = rn.GetValue<string>("grouped"),
               Override = rn.GetValue<string>("override"),
               Patch_Num = rn.GetValue<string>("patch_num"),
               PublishedDate = rn.PublicationDate,
               Risk = rn.GetValue<Lstring>("risk"),
               Title = rn.GetValue<string>("Title"),
               Summary = rn.GetValue<Lstring>("summary"),
               Prod_Name = rn.GetValue<Lstring>("prod_name"),
               ReleaseNoteParent = releaseNoteItemParent,
               McProductId = GetMcProductId(rn.GetRelatedItems("McProducts").Cast<DynamicContent>()),

           }).ToList();

       }
```

---

Is there any way to optimize this all into one query or a better way of doing this? Taking almost a minute to map this objects is too long for what we need to do with them.

If there is no way we will have to cache the items or make a SQL query. I would rather not do caching or SQL query if I do not have to.

Thank you in advance for any and all help you can provide, I am new to posting questions on stackoverflow so if you need any additional data please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are doing a `.ToList()` for the items? Is it possible for you to avoid that. In my opinion, most of the time(of the 1 minute) is taken to convert all your items into a list. Conversion from Sitefinity object to C# object is not the culprit here.

Comment: Are you talking about the 2nd method, GetReleaseNoteItemsByReleaseNoteParent?

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, I am talking about the 2nd method.

Comment: I never thought about the tolist being the slow down. Thank you very much, it is now much faster less than a second. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look Arno's answer here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/112295105425490148444/posts/QrsVtxj1sCB?cfem=1

You can use the "Content links manager" to query dynamic modules relationships (both by parent -ParentItemId- or by child -ChildItemId-) much faster:

```
var providerName = String.Empty;
var parentTitle = "Parent";
var relatedTitle = "RelatedItem3";

DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager(providerName);
Type parentType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.ParentModules.ParentModule");
Type relatedType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.RelatedModules.RelatedModule");

ContentLinksManager contentLinksManager = ContentLinksManager.GetManager();

// get the live version of all parent items
var parentItems = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(parentType).Where(i => i.GetValue<string>("Title").Contains(parentTitle) && i.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && i.Visible);

// get the ids of the related items.
// We use the OriginalContentId property since we work with the live vesrions of the dynamic modules
var parentItemIds = parentItems.Select(i => i.OriginalContentId).ToList();

// get the live versions of all the schedules items
var relatedItems = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(relatedType).Where(i => i.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && i.Visible && i.GetValue<string>("Title").Contains(relatedTitle));

// get the content links
var contentLinks = contentLinksManager.GetContentLinks().Where(cl => cl.ParentItemType == parentType.FullName && cl.ComponentPropertyName == "RelatedField" && parentItemIds.Contains(cl.ParentItemId) && cl.AvailableForLive);

// get the IDs of the desired parent items
var filteredParentItemIds = contentLinks.Join<ContentLink, DynamicContent, Guid, Guid>(relatedItems, (cl) => cl.ChildItemId, (i) => i.OriginalContentId, (cl, i) => cl.ParentItemId).Distinct();

// get the desired parent items by the filtered IDs
var filteredParentItems = parentItems.Where(i => filteredParentItemIds.Contains(i.OriginalContentId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Everyone keeps saying it is the related data, I must be missing something. The first method GetAllLiveReleaseNoteItemsByReleaseNoteParentId takes less than a second. And the 2nd method, GetReleaseNoteItemsByReleaseNoteParent even after removing the related data (McProductId completely) it is still taking roughly 40 seconds. Where is the related data once that is removed?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that every release note item under a single release note would be related to the same product wouldn't it?

If so, do you need to do the GetMcProductId method for every item?

Comment: I can actually remove GetMcProductId completely and it still takes a long time.